# Cannot dump svn repository

Tags: svn

I've a problem with my svn repo. I cannot use it, I even cannot dump it.

```
svnadmin verify repo
```

returns

```
Can't set position pointer in file 'svn/db/revs/0/0'
```

When I try to dump repo (no matter what revision range), console output shows:

```
* Dumped revision 0.
svnadmin: Final line in revision file missing space
```

I've googled that this may be connected with wrong version apr apache2 library, but I have other repositories which work good, so I thing this isn't the case.

Is there any way to **save** at least some files from my repo? Can svn repo get corrupted so easily (probably after power-cut, however I'm not sure).

Comment: Are the permissions set so that your user (or the user the web server is running as) can write to that location? I've seen things like this when somehow the filesystem permissions on the repo have got borked - a chown -R sorted that out.

Answer (score -1):

Did you run `svnadmin repair [path to repo]`?

Check for a missing or damaged file. If you are running on Windows, verify that the file is in UNIX format (`\n`) and not Windows format (`\n\r`).

Worst case, copy in a replacement file. It works for revprops (comment files), haven't tried it for revs (data files).

Comment: 'svnadmin repair'? what's that? 0_o